# Using set_data for matplotlib with multiple rows of data

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I want a simple implementation of  dynamic plot and found that `plt.set_data` seemed to work using `plt.draw()` and `plt.pause()`. However I can not get it to work when I have multiple rows of data that I want to plot as individual line (I do not want to use a for-loop). Se code and result below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

x = np.array([[1,2,3],
              [4,5,6],
              [8,9,10]]).T

y = np.array([[3,3,3],
              [5,7,5],
              [3,1,3]]).T

plt.plot(x, y, 'lightgreen', linewidth = 5, label = 'Wanted dynamic plot')


dynamic_t, = plt.plot([], [], 'b--', label = 'Transposed data')
dynamic_t.set_data(x.T,y.T)

dynamic, = plt.plot([], [], 'r--', label = 'Not transposed data')
dynamic.set_data(x,y)

plt.axis([0,10,0,10])
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

With the following resulting plot:
[image]

If I transpose the data (blue line) I get the correct sequence of lines however I get them as one continous line but I want there to be three individual ones.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why the opposition to a loop? `set_data` accepts an array of shape `(2, N)` or two arrays of shape `(1, N)` - you can't use it to set the data for three separate lines in a single call. The best approach here is to use a list of artists and to iterate over it calling `set_data` for each one individually.

Comment: @WilliamMiller the reason i do not want to use a for loop is because the number of lines that I want to plot can change in between runs.